# Shibboleth Service Provider for SAML authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, saml-2.0, shibboleth

Hi we are building an application in ASP.Net using .net framework 4.0, IIS 7. we are trying to use SAML(2.0) authentication. We have an identity provider whose login credentials will be used by our application. The Service provider being used is SHIBBOLETH (2x).
If any one has used shibboleth could you please let me know the installation and how to test whether its working. 
I currently did every step present here https://shibboleth.usc.edu/docs/sp/install/#configure
The shibboleth service is running all the configurations is done.
But im not understanding the Testing shibboleth phase.
How would I have this login page, where would I login using the credentials.
Please give some detailed advice as I new to this

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, you can either use the [WIF Extension for SAML 2.0 Protocol](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/card/archive/2011/05/16/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview.aspx)  or go standard WIF -> ADFS -> SAML -> Shibboleth.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install Shibboleth SP3 executable [Download link](https://shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/), Make sure you checked the configure IIS7 module and let the other as default options. This process will install Shibboleth SP3 in C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\ directory.

visit http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Status to see the status (on your server, don't use IP or domain it will throw 403).

Then Configure shibboleth2.xml as per your need. Visit  http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/Login and it will redirect you to IDP login page.

> I have attached the blog post below which has complete details with
>   screenshots.

**Here is a complete article about** [Shibboleth Service Provider for IIS](https://blogs.yunus.in/shibboleth-service-provider-for-iis)